# simpleXML Select based on value of 2 fields

Tags: php, simplexml

I have some xml that defines a list of properties that are either residential or commercial. They are also split into for sale or to let. Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<property>
    <property_ref>768</property_ref>
    <building_number></building_number>
    <address1>Celia Fiennes House, 8-20 Well Street, London, E9 7PX</address1>
    <address2>Celia Fiennes House</address2>
    <address3>8-20 Well Street</address3>
    <town>London</town>
    <county>London</county>
    <region>London.</region>
    <country>ENGLAND</country>
    <postcode>E9 7PX</postcode>
    <property_types>

        <type_description>Office</type_description>

    </property_types>
    <job_type>Disposal (Sale/Let)</job_type>
    <property_status>To Let</property_status>
```

......

I need to be able to select a property based on the property_types->type-description field and also the job_type value. I've managed to select properties based on the type_description value:

```
foreach($xml->children() as $property)
        {
            // check property_types
            $selectProperty = false;

            foreach ($property->property_types->type_description as $type)
            {
                if($type == "my value")
                {
                    $selectProperty = true;
                }
            }

            if($selectProperty)
            {
                // show the property on this page...
```

But, how do I also check the value of the job_type?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you also check for job_type like this?

```
if ($selectProperty && (string)$property->job_type == 'my job type')
  {
    // show the property on this page...
```

It would seem pretty simple to check the job type before or after checking the type description and then combine the boolean result of each check with a logical AND operator.